# How do I check if a named group exists in a MatchData object?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > result = "test string".match(/(?<mtch>test)/)
 => #<MatchData "test" mtch:"test"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011 > result["mtch"]
 => "test" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :012 > result["fail"]
IndexError: undefined group name reference: fail
    from (irb):12:in `[]'
    from (irb):12
    from /Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

There isn't a MatchData function for checking whether a named group exists.  is there some other way to check?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
result.names.include? 'mtch'
# => true
result.names.include? 'fail'
# => false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result["fail"] rescue false
```

is one simple way. There are more elegant ways, but the rescue modifier comes often handy, it's simple if you don't want to pay attention to exceptions thrown.

Comment: Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: Depends. Sometimes you really don't care whether there was in exception (like when you know that not having a match causes one). I use it sparingly, but I don't consider it bad style.

Comment: But using result.names.include? is much better, IMO, like Mladen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect the matched data by using `p`. In your case, the example already shows what you have.

```
=> #<MatchData "test" mtch:"test">
```

This means that the entire string that matched is `"test"`, and the inventory of the name is (only) `mtch`. If it had some other name, it would be included in this form.